# Where to initialize a library in react (like service in angular)

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to react and using a library named `react-use-intercom`, there is a `IntercomProvider` that I add to App.tsx, in order to add the provider to all my component.

```
const App = () => (
  <IntercomProvider appId={INTERCOM_APP_ID}>
    <HomePage />
  </IntercomProvider>
);
```

But then, I need to boot the intercom from somewhere  with some additional parameter (like the language, userinfo etc...) Coming from some app hooks and a graphql query. something like below.

```
export default () => {
  const { boot } = useIntercom();
  const {
    i18n: { language },
  } = useTranslation();

  const { data } = useQuery<UserForIntercom, UserForIntercomVariables>(
    USER_FOR_INTERCOM
  );

  boot({
    ...{
      user_id: data?.user?.id,
      email: data?.user?.email || '',
      name: data?.user?.name,
    },
    languageOverride: language || 'en',
  });

  return <></>;
};
```

But here I just render a component that render nothing and do some stuff. I was thinking of making a one time hook called somewhere in the app to initialize only once the component. But I wonder what is a place where I can isolate this logic, and that would make sense in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** Having a super quick read of the docs, you can ignore my original answer below.

The docs outline exactly what you are trying to do, so I would recommend to simply follow that approach instead:

```
// Anywhere in the consuming components render function
const bootWithProps = () => boot({ name: 'Russo' });

// Later when you want to initiate intercom
<button onClick={bootWithProps}>Boot with props</button>
```

## Old answer

If its only used on the `<HomePage/>` you could add it to that component, or if its used in multiple, you could have it as a sibling to `<HomePage/>`

I'm not familiar with Intercom specifically though so the hierarchy may need to be flipped, but should give you a general idea:

### Main app

```
const App = () => (
  <IntercomProvider appId={INTERCOM_APP_ID}>
    <BootstrapIntercom/>
    <HomePage />
  </IntercomProvider>
);
```

### BootstrapIntercom.jsx

```
const BootstrapIntercom = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // configure Intercom whenever user changes
        configureIntercom(data.user)
    }, [data.user]);

    return props.children;
}
```

### configureIntercom.js

```
export const configureIntercom = (user) => {
  // your code from your question
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the thing is, this part `const bootWithProps = () => boot({ name: 'Russo' });` the props I pass require some logic (api call etc..) and I didn't want to pollute a component with logic for the intercom, I wanted to separate this logic somewhere. But I guess then this is not possible ?

Comment: Like, in that place I would boot it up (in a executed only once method) and then hide/show using the hooks provided by the library. is an empty component bad ?

Comment: @Bobby Yeah I agree about not polluting thats why I pushed it out to "configureIntercom.js" in my first example. If you follow the doc approach, you can still extract it out into a small bootstrap file that does the configuration (but isn't a component)